# Django raw sql %d for ID not working for integer parameters

Tags: django, sqlite

I have this raw sql for my Django model:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT crowdfunding_offering.offering_name FROM crowdfunding_offering WHERE crowdfunding_offering.id = %d ORDER BY crowdfunding_offering.id DESC LIMIT 1', (int(self.offering.id),))
```

Which does not work. I am receiving this error:

```
Exception Value:    near "%": syntax error
```

Then I try to change `%d` to `%s`, only then it works. I thought `%d` are for number parameters and `%s` are for strings, but why is it not working for `%d`?

Here is the table with the id clearly being an integer:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django's raw SQL queries, [placeholders are always `%s`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw), not `%d` or anything else.

```
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
```

You can also use `%(foo)s` if your parameters are in a dict:

```
Person.objects.raw(
    'SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %(lname)s',
    {"lname": lname},
)
```

Comment: thank you. by the way, Is the above query on my question safe from sql injection?

Comment: Yes, since you're not interpolating anything into the SQL query using `%` (see the warning in the documentation link).

Comment: The question is, though, why use raw SQL? `Offering.objects.filter(id=self.offering.id).values_list('offering_name', flat=True)[:1]` is equivalent; you can iterate that queryset for a list of strings.

Comment: that was simplified. I was using left join and being new to django, I opted for raw sqls for it.